# Is it possible to limit a IP's traffic in gateway Juniper switch?

Tags: switch, juniper, networking

In my gateway Juniper Switch:

```
...
irb {
    unit 0 {
        family inet;
    }
    unit 2 {
        family inet {
            address 10.10.10.254/24;
        }
    }
    unit 9 {
        family inet {
            address 40.224.224.14/29;
        }
    }

  ...
```

I want to limit the IP `40.224.224.1`'s traffic in my gateway device, how to realize this?

I hear about use `filter` can do it, but I am not sure of this.

my gateway switch is: Juniper EX4300.

---

**EDIT-01**

thanks Vink's response, but my attempt seems go wrong:

I write a filter:

```
admin@C1-A# show firewall family inet filter Egress-SVI-filter
term Limit-traffic {
    from {
        source-address {
            40.224.224.1/32;
            40.224.224.2/32;
        }
    }
    then policer Limit-200m;
}
```

and apply it to a SVI:

```
admin@C1-A# show interfaces irb unit 96
family inet {
    filter {
        output Egress-SVI-filter;
    }
    address 40.224.224.6/29;
}
```

but the `40.224.224.1-2` will be uncommunicative right now.

My policer:

```
admin@C1-A# show firewall policer Limit-200m
filter-specific;
if-exceeding {
    bandwidth-limit 200m;
    burst-size-limit 40m;
}
then discard;
```

---

**EDIT-02**

I tried change the term to like this:

```
admin@C1-A# show firewall family inet filter Egress-SVI-filter
term Limit-traffic {
    from {
        source-address {
            40.224.224.1/32;
            40.224.224.2/32;
        }
    }
    then {
        policer Limit-200m;
        accept;
    }
}
```

but still will cause the network uncommunicate.

---

**Edit-03**

[image]

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more context on what you're trying to achieve and the setup you're using if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: @TeunVink i want to limit 40.224.224.1and 2 egress traffic to 200m.

Comment: As @RobinG mentioned you need an explicit permit policy at the end of your filter.

Comment: @TeunVink See my EDIT-02, friend. it still not work.

Comment: You're talking about an egress filter but are matching source adresses on an output filter, either that doesn't make sense and you should be matching destination addresses or I don't understand your topology and exactly what you're filtering.

Comment: for server, it's the egress.

Comment: As I've said two times before now, please provide a clear description of your topology, interfaces and what you're trying to achieve, especially where you want to police and in what direction. It's impossible to  answer your question properly if you're only providing pieces of the puzzle every time someone posts an answer.

Comment: See my **Edit-03**, I have updated it.

Comment: You still don't have a generic accept policy for cases when the policer does *not* match. That should be a separate term in your filter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply a filter to an interface in the interface:

```
irb {
    unit 9 {
        family inet {
            address 40.224.224.14/29;
            filter input my-filter;
        }
    }
}
```

And then define that filter under `firewall family inet`:

```
firewall {
    family inet {
        filter my-filter {
            term one {
                # filter criteria and actions
            }
            term two {
                # some more criteria and actions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more on how to configure this filters in this free Juniper ebook: [Day One: Configuring Junos Policies and Firewall Filters](https://www.juniper.net/us/en/training/jnbooks/day-one/fundamentals-series/configuring-junos-policies/).

Comment: can you give me an example of how to judge a special IP(`40.224.224.1`) then limit its traffic to `200m`?

Comment: I tried, but seems get wrong .

Comment: Do not forget to add a term at the end accepting all other traffic, the default action for a filter is drop.

Answer (score 5):

Adjust your filter to allow all other traffic - at the moment, you are blocking everything except the two IP addresses in question.

```
term Limit-traffic {
    from {
        source-address {
            40.224.224.1/32;
            40.224.224.2/32;
        }
    }
    then {
        policer Limit-200m;
        accept;
    }
}
term Permit-All-Else {      <---- Add an allow-all term 
    then accept;
}
```

Comment: give you the upvote, thanks for the detail answer.